# Culture Aware Currency Formatting in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization, telerik

I would like to format a currency value being bound to a a cell/column in a data grid.

The relevant XAML is as follows:

```
<telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="dataGrid" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,25,0,0" IsSearchingDeferred="True" 
    IsReadOnly="True" IsLocalizationLanguageRespected="False">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=VALUATION, StringFormat=C}" 
            Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.AddressLine3}"/>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

This is the value that is currently being bound to the column (the value is coming from a database as number literal):

```
12345678.90
```

This is the value that is output when the culture is set to `en-US`

```
12345678.90 //notice the decimal point
```

This is the value that is output when the culture is set to `nl-NL`

```
12345678,90 //notice the comma
```

You can see that the culture is being respected to some extent. However, the output isn't what I would expect.

For the `en-US` culture I would like the output to be `$12,345,678.90`. For the `nl-NL` culture I would like the output to be `€ 12.345.680,00`.

In my XAML code behind of have manually set the culture (for testing purposes) using the following code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    //I am toggling between the following cultures
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
    //CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
    //CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    //I am forcing the UI to use the culture I specify
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(ci.Name);
    Properties.Resources.Culture = ci;

    //these are used to test that to string formatting works as expected
    //when using the debugger
    float price = 12345678.90F;
    string currencyToDisplay = price.ToString("C");

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

**Question**

Why isn't the format showing currency symbols and number delimiters even though I have specified the format as currency?

Manually, formatting the same number in code behind gives me the results that I would like, but I would like to do this in XAML.

**What I have tried**
I have tried the following workarounds to no avail:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=VALUATION, StringFormat=C}" Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.AddressLine3}"/>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=VALUATION, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.AddressLine3}"/>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=VALUATION, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}" Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.AddressLine3}"/>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=VALUATION, StringFormat='C'}" Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.AddressLine3}"/>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=VALUATION, StringFormat=c}" Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.AddressLine3}"/>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding VALUATION}" DataFormatString="{}{0:C}" Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.AddressLine3}"/>
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Your code should work fine and show currency symbol, problem is somewhere else. Can you show definition of your class you bind to (class which contains VALUATION property)?

Comment: The is no class definition being used for binding. The binding is being done to a data table returned by a SQL query. The name of the data grid is `dataGrid` and the data is being bound in the following manner `dataGrid.ItemsSource = ToDataTable(results).DefaultView;`. The data binds with no problems.

Comment: As a wild guess - maybe you already convert your number to string _before_ binding takes place, so that VALUATION is already of type String (not decimal\float) in that data table.

Comment: If that's the case (and I think you're right) what's the recommended course of action? I would like to stay away from needing to create a class for binding. Would also like to avoid code behind.

Comment: You could use a converter for your Binding and even check this way if the value that you are getting is `string` or `double`. BTW if you are using this in a UserControl you need to set the culture info in there as well, XAML `xml:lang="nl-NL"`

Comment: @XAMlMAX I used your suggestion and found [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) site to setup my converter. Using what you said to use my custom converter as a way to debug the value allowed me to find out that it was being converted to a string at an earlier point in code execution. Stopping that allowed me to use the default currency converter. Thanks a lot for your help! If you can post that as a possible solution I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we spoke in the comments.
Possible reason for not showing the currency sign is that the `UserControl` that you were using wasn't using correct culture. I have found similar behavior when I used `DynamicResource` to style a `Button` without including the `ResourceDictionary` in the xaml. What I mean is that style was applied partially, like in your case when dot became comma but without currency sign.
One way to force the `UserCpntrol` to use the desired culture is to include this snippet in your `UserControl` xaml file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Views.CultureExplicitUC"
             xml:lang="en-GB"<!--This is what you want in your UC-->
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now for the converter you need to create class that looks like this:

```
namespace WpfApplication1.Converters
{
    public class DebugConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //manipulate your data here
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that the converter has a cultureInfo as a parameter so if needed you can manually change it depending on the circumstances of your development.
Also by using converter you can determine what type of data is being passed into by doing a simple check like:
`if(value is int)`